# VS2012 Database Project Validation

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I've set up a new Visual Studio 2012 Database Project to hold the assets for a database and I'm having problems getting the project to build properly. The issue that I'm facing is that we have custom code within our database scripts that does certain evaluations when executed. This is by design, and works well. However because it's more complex than the standard database script (for say a table) the project won't build. I'd like to turn off the validation   so that the project can build and deploy without being failing the build. Is there a way to turn off the validation portion of the project? I'm new to working with DB project types in VS, so not sure what all may be available. Any other strategies or work-arounds are also welcome.

Comment: Can you give a couple examples of this custom complex code? Where does it live?

Comment: Yes, the complexity is basically a way to manage table objects and how to handle those objects if they have existing data. So I have a reference row for each table in the database and the reference holds details such as is this the first deploy of the table and can the table be dropped and fully repopulated, or does it need to manage the DDL changes differently (as in Alter table...etc). Depending on the values of the lookup columns in this table our base script for each table has logic embedded to manage how changes are rolled out.

Comment: I think you're looking at a paradigm shift when using SSDT. SQL Projects are designed to make your target DB look like your project. It will ALTER, CREATE, and optionally DROP to make your database look like the project. You'll need to handle those types of changes a bit differently. For empty tables, I'd probably just let the project make the changes. Even for existing tables, the project will attempt to keep the existing data. My blog might help or some of this: http://schottsql.blogspot.com/2013/10/all-ssdt-articles.html

Comment: When you say "For existing tables, the project will attempt to keep the existing data", how is this handled? In testing with a smaller database I found that the build would fail if any exceptions were encountered. (ie. going from a datatype of varchar(50) to varchar(40)) which would potentially cause data loss. I didn't see a way to handle the exceptions, it just fails the build.

Comment: There's an option to let it continue on potential data loss. Normally you won't have something like this, but if you put a "pre-deploy" script in place to make sure that the data will work, you can use this without too much trouble.